# Store scrapy items to process after spider completes

Tags: python, signals, scrapy, pipeline

I'm working on writing a scrapy pipeline that will call a function to clear our cdn's edge servers of the scraped urls. I figured out how to store the list of visited urls easily enough, but the issue is knowing when the crawler is done.

The cdn's api takes urls in batches of 100, so I can easily call it's clear function every 100 urls, but if there are 543 urls to crawl the last 43 won't get sent to the cdn's clear function.

I've been looking at the scrapy signal documentation, but I can't figure out if

1. the spider_closed signal is called when the last request is received or when all item are through the pipeline. If it's the latter, it's too late to know to call the api with the last 43 urls
2. the other option would be to add an extension that calls the cdn's api when it receives the spider_closed signal, but how does it know all the urls that the spider has seen? I can build a list of them in the item pipeline, but how to get that to the extension? (I could maybe use the item_scraped signal, which just occurred to me.)

So yeah, is there a way to know, inside the pipeline, when the are no more items coming? And are there multiple pipelines running concurrently, or is each pipeline a singleton?

Answer (score 2):

So I found that there's a function that is called in every pipelines when the spider closes after it's finished crawling and everything is through the pipeline, which is

```
def close_spider(self, spider):
    pass
```

There's also a function called on startup, which is

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    pass
```